# Can't render Material UI React Grid properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, grid

I am trying to render responsive grid with this code:

```
<div className={"root"}>
            <NavigationMenu pageName={"Report"}>
                <Container maxWidth="lg" className={"container"}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
                            <Paper className={"paper"}>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={8}>
                            <Paper className={"paper"}>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
                            <Paper className={"paper"}>
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </NavigationMenu>
        </div>
```

But the render result comes out like this:
[Render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyc3.png)

But i want this:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYNEK.png)

My guess is that its some css issue but i couldn't identify it.

---

[https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7602](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyc3.png)

I can see that demo on the official page gives same result, I guess that's just the way Grid works.

[codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6wezp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYNEK.png)

I have found this to solve my problem:
https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css

Comment: You need to have two vertical with 4 and 8. Then in column 4 you will put 2 boxes with 12 column each so that will make 2 rows on left in first column. And in your second column will have the remaining right area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material UI Grid also has direction. So you can create 1 grid with row direction and then 2 more nested grids inside with column directions. And then your 2 smaller "Papers" will just go into the 1st Grid with column direction. This should give you your expected result.